# Disable time showing in UIDatePicker after current time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my device I have set my timezone "Canada/Toronto". I am using UIDatePicker and I want to show Indian date and time in it. It is showing the date and time but it is not restricting my time it is letting me select future time too.

for example if Canada time is 5:00 AM
still the Datepicker should show Indian time i.e IST
so if Indian time is 8:00 PM then it should disable all time after 8:00 PM

```
    let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    // Posiiton date picket within a view
    datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
    // Set some of UIDatePicker properties
    datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Kolkata")
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
    //print(datePicker.date)
    // Add an event to call onDidChangeDate function when value is changed.
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    // Add DataPicker to the view
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What do you mean with "future time"? Please provide an example (current local time, time in Kolkata, time selected in the picker view), telling us what you see and what you would expect.

Comment: Like if time in India is 8:00 pm. it is allowing me to select time 8:05 pm also which I don't want

Comment: If in canada it's 5 AM (GMT-5), then GMT is 10 AM. Kolkata is GMT+5:30, which is 15:30 (or 3:30 PM).  On my computer, it behaves like this. I can only choose date/time until 15:30 (3:30 PM), not further. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Or are you currently living in India, and just your device is set to canadian local time?

Comment: I have set my device in Canadian local time. But I want to render Indian time on UI.

Comment: Can you just print out the value of `Date()` and check what the maximum selectable date in the picker is?